# SVM multiclass classification halts when training data using scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, multiclass-classification

I'm using scikit & svm to classify data into 7 classes. The data is audio, and I've sliced them into 30 millisecond frames.
At the end, there are about 1 million frames each used as a labelled sample with 13 mfcc features.
when fitting data as in the following code, my cpu stays at about 20 percent usage and nothing happens! I've waited about 30 hours, but it has not been completed yet.
Is it about the number of samples being too much?!!

```
clf = SVC(C=20.0, gamma=0.00001)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train) #This is where it gets stuck
```

Comment: You can set `verbose=True` to have it report periodically on the model training, and you can set `max_iter` to limit the number of iterations the model will go through during fitting. You `gamma` value also strikes me as very small, default is 1/n_features, so in your case, `1/13=0.07`. You can also try other kernels and c values, but `verbose` is a good way to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html).

> The fit time scales at least quadratically with the number of samples and may be impractical beyond tens of thousands of samples

Moreover, since you are using a multiclass problem with 7 classes and since

> The multiclass support is handled according to a one-vs-one scheme.

you are training 21(!) classifiers, see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsOneClassifier.html).

The documentation recommends:

> For large datasets consider using `sklearn.linear_model.LinearSVC` or `sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier` instead, possibly after a `sklearn.kernel_approximation.Nystroem` transformer.

Did you consider to run a neural network somehow?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About SVM itself, I somehow managed to reduce the size of frames using DTW algorithm, then applied SVM over 39 mfccs, which yielded a better accuracy (62%) compared to SGD Classifier (~30%) or LinearSVC (40%). I should try a neural network now.

Answer (score 0):

As Quickbeam2k1 answer details, SVM does not scale well to this many samples.

I recommend trying a small neural network instead. A Multi Layer Perceptron with maybe 3-5 hidden layers of 50 neurons each should be an OK starting point for 13-band MFCC and 7 classes. With scikit-learn you can use [sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html).